# How to query table to get current total count including previous dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get the **current** total count of registered users by the day in an SQL Database from this data:

```
| userID   | date_registered |
| -------- | --------------- |
| 10012    | 2021-03-01      |
| 10043    | 2021-03-01      |
| 10065    | 2021-03-04      |
| 10087    | 2021-03-05      |
| 10091    | 2021-03-05      |
| 10123    | 2021-03-05      |
| 10231    | 2021-03-06      |
| 10421    | 2021-03-09      |
```

So for 2021-03-01, there are currently 2 registered users.

For 2021-03-04, there are currently 3 registered users (including registers from previous dates)

For 2021-03-05, there are currently 6 registered users (including registers from previous dates)

and so on...

So the expected result should be

```
| total_user | date            |
| ---------- | --------------- |
| 2          | 2021-03-01      |
| 3          | 2021-03-04      |
| 6          | 2021-03-05      |
| 7          | 2021-03-06      |
| 8          | 2021-03-09      |
```

Is there an SQL query possible to accomplish this result in BigQuery?

Much appreciated the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In BigQuery or any reasonable database, we can aggregate by date and then use `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY date_registered) AS total_user,
    date_registered AS date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    date_registered
ORDER BY
    date_registered;
```

Note that if the same user might be reported more than once on a given date, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT userID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but there are more practical ways for mysql 8+

```
SELECT e1.date_registered, (SELECT COUNT(e2.userID) FROM example e2 
WHERE e2.date_registered <= e1.date_registered) AS count_ FROM example e1
GROUP BY date_registered
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e3cd/16)

Comment: There's an error in BigQuery: "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."